# Selenium not selecting dropdown in Python, no errors

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select field where I can input text (a date) and then select a dropdown menu that has a list of years/months. The dropdown is not available until a date is put into the text field. In my code, I do get Python to press the tab button so that the dropdown menu becomes accessible.

I have a feeling this has to do with frames but I really have no clue. This code does nothing (but does not throw any errors):

```
date = driver.find_element_by_id('ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue')
date.click()
date.send_keys(asOfDate)
```

But it works when I add this above it (I found this in a previous project similar to mine; don't know what it does!):

```
Elem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe:not([id]):not([name])")))
```

Great, but now I'm trying to interact with the dropdown menu:

```
dropdown = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'ReportViewerControl_ct104_ct105_ddValue'))))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text('2016.01')
```

And nothing happens. No errors, just nothing. So I'm guessing it's the same problem as before.

This does nothing either:

```
dropdown2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue"))
dropdown2.select_by_visible_text('2016.01')
```

In fact, I can't even click on it in Python (the following code does nothing as well):

```
dropdown3 = driver.find_element_by_id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue")
dropdown3.click()
```

So what's going on? Why am I unable to interact with the dropdown menu?

Edit: here is a chunk of the HTML code:

```
<div onclick="if ($get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" onactivate="if ($get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04') != null &amp;&amp; $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewerControl_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="ParameterTable_ReportViewerControl_ctl04" name="ParameterTable_ReportViewerControl_ctl04" class="ParametersFrame ParamsGrid MenuBarBkGnd">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td width="100%" height="100%"><table id="ParametersGridReportViewerControl_ctl04">
                            <tbody><tr isparameterrow="true">
                                <td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue"><span>as Of</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03" data-parametername="asOf">
                                    <div onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                                        <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue" type="text" value="1/1/2018" size="28" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$txtValue\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue" class="null">&nbsp;<input src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Calendar.png" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl03$ddDropDownButton" type="image" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton" alt="Select a value" title="Select a value" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                    </div>
                                </div></td><td class="InterParamPadding"></td><td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue"><span>Vintage</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05" data-parametername="vintage">
                                    <select name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl05$ddValue" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl05_ddValue" class="aspNetDisabled">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="075d73ab-eeb5-4b4e-b838-28b1cbb053b4">&lt;Select&nbsp;a&nbsp;Value&gt;</option>
                                        <option value="2016.01">2016.01</option>
                                        <option value="2016.02">2016.02</option>
                                        <option value="2016.03">2016.03</option>
                                        <option value="2016.04">2016.04</option>
                                        <option value="2016.05">2016.05</option>
                                        <option value="2016.06">2016.06</option>
                                        <option value="2016.07">2016.07</option>
                                        <option value="2016.08">2016.08</option>
                                        <option value="2016.09">2016.09</option>
                                        <option value="2016.10">2016.10</option>
                                        <option value="2016.11">2016.11</option>
                                        <option value="2016.12">2016.12</option>
                                        <option value="2017.01">2017.01</option>
                                        <option value="2017.02">2017.02</option>
                                        <option value="2017.03">2017.03</option>
                                        <option value="2017.04">2017.04</option>
                                        <option value="2017.05">2017.05</option>
                                        <option value="2017.06">2017.06</option>
                                        <option value="2017.07">2017.07</option>
                                        <option value="2017.08">2017.08</option>
                                        <option value="2017.09">2017.09</option>
                                        <option value="2017.10">2017.10</option>
                                        <option value="2017.11">2017.11</option>
                                        <option value="2017.12">2017.12</option>
                                        <option value="2018.01">2018.01</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div></td>
                            </tr><tr isparameterrow="true">
                                <td class="ParamLabelCell"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_txtValue"><span>Cut Off Date</span></label></td><td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;"><div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07" data-parametername="cutOffDate">
                                    <div onactivate="event.cancelBubble=true;" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                                        <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$txtValue" type="text" size="28" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_txtValue" disabled="" class="DisabledTextBox">&nbsp;<input src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=13.0.1601.5&amp;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Calendar_Disabled.png" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$ddDropDownButton" type="image" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_ddDropDownButton" alt="Select a value" title="Select a value" style="cursor:default;" disabled="">&nbsp;<span class="aspNetDisabled" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_cbNull" type="checkbox" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$cbNull" checked="checked" aria-label="Cut Off Date: NULL"><label for="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_cbNull">NULL</label></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div></td><td class="InterParamPadding"></td><td></td><td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table></td><td width="6px"></td><td class="SubmitButtonCell"><table>
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl00" value="View Report" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Share us the link to the page or relevant HTML block

Comment: You can trace it with the help of Debug.

Comment: I added useful HTML code. I'm not quite sure how to use the debugger. I haven't coded consistently for about 8 years and so I am getting back into this slowly. I'll try and look into debugging the code, but if you could provide useful tips as to what I should look for when debugging (or rather, how I would go about doing to--aside from hitting the "debug" button), it would be appreciated.